# Hello.why does html and css dosen't link?

Tags: html, css

Why html and css wont link?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css,style.style">
```

I googled it and watched on YouTube beside i did the exact same the way they did it just not working the html and css both of them are in the same folder with the link

Comment: Can you copy the relevant linking code into your question again? It seems broken. It would also help to know what the filename of your CSS file is.

Comment: For a start, your URL should look a bit more like this: `./css/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to give the relevant path to your css file in `href`. In your code you have added a "," ,which makes it bit unclear.Change it to a "/".

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href=".css/style.css">
```